# return возвращает всегда только одно последнее значение из цикла for (Django)

Tags: python, django, requests, for

`context_processors.py`:

```py
from .models import Category, Product


def all_cattegory(request):
   products = Product.objects.filter(published=True)
   categories = Category.objects.filter(published=True)
   user_k = f'{request.user.usrid.discount_list_k1}'

   for post in products:
      post = max(float(post.id_p), float(user_k))
      print(post)
   return {"categories": categories, "products": products,"post": post }
```

return возвращает всегда только одно последнее значение из цикла

Comment: а что должен возвращать?

Comment: список) верное решение снизу . Только непонятно теперь как в шаблоне вывести значение для каждого продукта. А то в цикле для каждого создается дубль список.

Comment: может нужен ключ  post[0] это как пример чтобы вывести первый элемент а как вывести все элементы для продуктов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Естественное поведение так, как вы переписываете каждый раз переменную `post`. Для того чтобы хранить все значения в цикле вам нужен тип данных, который хранит набор. Например, `list`, то есть список

```py
....
   post = []
   for product in products:
      post.append(max(float(product.id_p), float(user_k)))
      print(post)
   return {"categories": categories, "products": products,"post": post }
```

Не очень понятны наборы данных, которые вы обрабатываете, поскольку и в самом цикле вы используете переменную `post`, а затем ее изменяете. То есть не понятна логика, что вы делаете.

`return` возвращает то, что вы ему передаете и он тут совершенно ни при чем. Вам необходимо добиться, чтобы переменная `post` содержала необходимые данные

Comment: Данное представление для расчета цен на товар и скидок покупателей. Берется max коэффициент

Comment: Спасибо! получился массив элементов для каждого продукта товаров. В цикле шаблона дублируется для каждого продукта, как сделать чтобы  в шаблоне в цикле  {% for product in products %}  {% endfor %} выводился корректно  по одному значению для каждого продукта! Заранее благодарю!

Comment: @slavyan насколько я понимаю это уже синстаксис джанго, для дополнительного вопроса создайте новую тему. В комментариях не удобно писать ни код и разъяснения

Comment: буду при много благодарен если объясните этот момент новичку https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1527205/

Comment: Ответа к сожалению не поступило)

Comment: @slavyan я очень редко отвечаю, и выборочно! Посмотрел, вопрос не понятен мне. Если вы написали тот код, который вы показываете, значит у вас не должно быть трудностей по поводу как минимум показать данные в консоли бэка и фронта. После того как вы получите данные на фронте, поймите как вы это дело обрабатываете. Если вы хотите получить ответ на ваш вопрос, то вот вам совет: добавьте результат который вы получаете сейчас, результат, который хотите получить и набор данных, которым вы манипулируете

Comment: Загрузил  скриншот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1527205/  сюда. Вывод хотелось  бы "discount_product_min'  был один для каждой строки свой соотвествующей проудкту айди. А в данный момент они списком грузятся для каждого продукта.