# Как вывести в шаблоне корректно значение в цикле?

Tags: python, django

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Получился массив элементов для каждого продукта товаров в цикле. В цикле шаблона дублируется для каждого продукта, как сделать чтобы в шаблоне в цикле {% for product in products %} {% endfor %} выводился корректно по одному значению для каждого продукта!

`views.py`:

```
    def product_list(request, category_slug=None, id_p=None):
        category = None
    
        categories = Category.objects.filter(published=True)
        products = Product.objects.filter(published =True)
    
        if category_slug:
            category = get_object_or_404(Category, category_id=category_slug)
            products = products.filter(category=category)
            paginator = Paginator(products, 100)  # Show 25 contacts per page.
            page = request.GET.get("page")
            user_k = f'{request.user.usrid.discount_list_k1}'
            post = []
            for product in products:
            post.append({"price_k": max(float(product.discount_product_min), 
                    float(user_k)) * float(product.price) })
            try:
                products = paginator.page(page)
            except PageNotAnInteger:
                products = paginator.page(1)
            except EmptyPage:
                products = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
        return render(request,
                      'shop/product/list.html',
                      {'category': category,
                       'categories': categories,
                       'products': products,
                       'post': post,
                       'page': page})
```

как сделать, чтобы {{post}} в шаблоне в цикле {% for product in products %} {% endfor %} выводился корректно по одному значению для каждого продукта?

`list.html`:

```
<div class="page collapse show">
        {% for product in products %}
        <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-lg-1 col-2 text-right text-muted">{{ product.id_p}}<br>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-7 col-lg-6 col-10">
                <div>
                    <a title="подробнее..." href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}" >{{ product.name }}
                        <div class="tumb" style="display: none;"><img src="{% if product.image %}{{ product.image.url }}{% else %}{% static "img/no_image.png" %}{% endif %}">
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="float-left small">
                    <span title="артикул товара: {{product.artikul}}" class="mr-3">
                        <i class="text-muted">арт:
                        </i>{{product.artikul}} 
                    </span>
                    <span title="в упаковке: {{ product.upakovka_f}}  {{ product.shtuk_e}}" class="mr-3"><i class="text-muted">упак: </i>{{ product.upakovka_f}} {{ product.shtuk_e}}
                    </span>
                    <span title="миним. норма отпуска {{ product.min_kol}} {{ product.shtuk_e}}">
                        <i class="text-muted ml-2">мин
                        </i>:&nbsp;{{ product.min_kol}} {{ product.shtuk_e}}
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="manufactur float-right small text-muted mr-2">ABRO
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-5 col-12">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                    <div class="123as">
                    <span class="text-muted small mr-1" title="в наличии более {{ product.stock}} ">{{ product.stock}} {{ product.shtuk_e}}
                    </span>
                        <i class="bi bi-patch-minus-fill" title="уменьшение">
                        </i>
                        <input class="inpbas" maxlength="5">
                        <i class="bi bi-patch-plus-fill" title="увеличение">
                        </i>
                    </div>
                        <x class="amount">**{{ post}}**
                        </x>

                    <div class="addbasket float-rigth">
                    <button class="addbutton" type="button" class="btn add"><i class="bi bi-cart-plus"></i>&nbsp;купить
                    </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Как один из вариантов начал добавлять словарь

```
 post.append({"price_k":max(float(product.discount_product_min), float(user_k)) * float(product.price) })
```

Потом хотел Обьект `products` модели превратить в словарь. и склеить их. Но не получилось их склеить